# How to install the module Entity Browser?

Tags: entities, drush

I'm trying to install the [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser) module, but I'm getting this error:

[image: Error]

It basically says that the "entity_browser" entity type does not exist, and based on the error I tried to install the missing entity type, using drush:

[image: Error running drush entup]

Once I ran `drusn entup` I was asked to install the missing entity, but drush ended returning the same error I'm getting in the browser.

Could I be missing something?

Comment: What steps did you take to install entity_browser?

Comment: And what version of Drupal and Drush?